# How to rdp into win2012r2 VM with vagrant but not log into a windows account?

Tags: windows, authentication, vagrant, virtualbox, rdp

Is there a way to power on and rdp into a windows box with vagrant but not log in to a windows account?

After I `vagrant rdp` I want to land on the windows login screen where I can select an account and enter a password. Is this possible?

Thank you very much for your time. Please let me know if you need any additional information or if I am being unclear.

Comment: Just start the VM from VirtualBox then and you'll see the default windows login screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Vagrantfile

```
#Vagrant 1.6+ natively supports Windows guests over WinRM.
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box = "opentable/win-2012r2-standard-amd64-nocm"

config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.7"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", host: 33389, guest: 3389
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
        v.name = "win_test"
        v.cpus = 2
        v.memory = 2048
    end
end
```

And command `vagrant rdp` brings prompt with logon where I type `vagrant` for login and password and get into guest.